# Change text color of a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a navigation menu bar. I want it so that one of the href links can change colors letter by letter without any mouse-over effect, if you know what I mean. Here's an example:

[image]
See how the "Create a Free Account" hyperlink switches from one color to another? That's what I'm referring to.

If this question sounds a little vague, I'll try to re-word it.

Comment: If you are looking for a mouse-over effect, check the CSS ":hover" selector. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: I want it so that every letter changes color automatically without any mouse-over effect.

Comment: Look at my answer below. It's what your lookin' for.

Comment: If you're looking to animate the color changing, letter by letter as you mentioned, you'll need JavaScript.

Comment: A static image is perhaps not the best way to show the animation you require...

Answer (score 2):

Try [Sliding letters with jQuery](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/05/09/sliding-letters-with-jquery/), you must use [lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/) plugin.

Example

```
<div class="sl_examples">
  <a href="#" id="example1" data-hover="Creativity">Illustrations</a>
</div>

.sl_examples{
   float:left;
   font-family: 'Bevan', arial, serif;
   font-size:50px;
   line-height:50px;
   color:#f0f0f0;
   margin-right:5px;
   text-transform:uppercase;
}
.sl_examples a{
   display:block;
   position:relative;
   float:left;
   clear:both;
   color:#fff;
}
.sl_examples a > span{
   height:50px;
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.sl_examples a span span{
   position:absolute;
   display:block;
   left:0px;
   top:0px;
   text-align:center;
}
.sl_examples a span span.sl-w1{
   color:#fff;
   text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #fff;
   z-index:2;
}  
.sl_examples a span span.sl-w2{
   color:#e82760;
   text-shadow:-1px 1px 2px #9f0633;
   z-index:3;
}


$(window).load(function() {
  $('#example1').hoverwords({ delay:50 });            
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place all the links in a DIV and then attach CSS a:hover to that div, like this:

**CSS**

```
#menu a {
    color: blue;
}
#menu a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by adding classes to the hyperlinks, 1 class for each colour.  E.G.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<a class="blue" href="#">Blue Hyperlink</a>
<a class="blue" href="#">Another Blue Hyperlink</a>
<a class="orange" href="#">Orange Hyperlink</a>
<a class="red" href="#">Red Hyperlink</a>

/* CSS */
.blue {
    color: #00F;
}

.orange {
    color: #FA0;
}

.red {
    color: #F00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this code within `head` tag. And change color codes as you wish. And remember that it (`css`) will apply to all of your hyperlinks.

```
<style type="text/css">
    <!--
        a:link {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #000000;
        }
        a:visited {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #000000;
        }
        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
            color: #CC9933;
        }
        a:active {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #006633;
        }
    -->
</style>
```